# Attract visitors to a website in it's begining with empty content

Tags: marketing, visitors

I am creating a customer to business website directory for my country, very similar to the way Yelp operates where people and businesses can add their company information. The website will have the usual reviews and customer search functions but the problem I am facing is how can I attract customers to visit the website for the first time when the website contains little information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To attract visitors, you need to have some value on your website.   Don't start off with an empty website:

- Write as many reviews yourself as possible
- Ask friends and family to help you out to write some too
- Hire some people to fill in your first set of reviews
- For businesses where you don't have reviews, figure out how else you can make sure the visitor will find what they want.  Link to your competition and say how many reviews they have.